# How to make a unique datetime without seconds?

Tags: mysql, innodb, datetime

I need to build a table accepting one row for each minute. If I set the type of primary key to `datetime`, 60 records can be added for each minute.

Is there any trick to design a table to keep `0000-00-00 00:00` unique?

Comment: Which version of MySQL ?

Comment: @ypercube 5.5 (more precise 5.5.35)

Comment: In 5.7 (and any MariaDB 5.3+ version) there are virtual columns that can be used for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store `CONCAT(LEFT(NOW(), 16), ':00')` into the `PRIMARY KEY` that is a `DATETIME`.

```
mysql> SELECT NOW(), CONCAT(LEFT(NOW(), 16), ':00');
+---------------------+--------------------------------+
| NOW()               | CONCAT(LEFT(NOW(), 16), ':00') |
+---------------------+--------------------------------+
| 2015-12-11 21:37:38 | 2015-12-11 21:37:00            |
+---------------------+--------------------------------+
```